# Text not being submitted to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a problem with simple bit of script and it only seems to be happening on the INESERTING into the database.

I have a form that also uploads an image to the server as well as putting the upload filename into the database, however. It seems that if an apostrophe is used, or quotes that are in UTF8 format are thrown out and the data is not submitted.

I've tried using mysql_real_escape_string and addslashes but it has the same effect or either doesn't post any information entered into the database.

Here is the form data (I've striped out the HTML coding to save space on this post)

```
<form method="post" action="inc/process-report.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="Title" type="text" class="NormalTextBox" />
<input name="ShortTitle" type="text" class="NormalTextBox" maxlength="50" />
<select name="date_d" class="NoSetWidthSelectBox">
        <option value'<? echo"$day"; ?>' selected><? echo"$day"; ?></option>
        <option value='01'>01</option>
        <option value='02'>02</option>
        <option value='03'>03</option>
        <option value='04'>04</option>
        <option value='05'>05</option>
        <option value='06'>06</option>
        <option value='07'>07</option>
        <option value='08'>08</option>
        <option value='09'>09</option>
        <option value='10'>10</option>
        <option value='11'>11</option>
        <option value='12'>12</option>
        <option value='13'>13</option>
        <option value='14'>14</option>
        <option value='15'>15</option>
        <option value='16'>16</option>
        <option value='17'>17</option>
        <option value='18'>18</option>
        <option value='19'>19</option>
        <option value='20'>20</option>
        <option value='21'>21</option>
        <option value='22'>22</option>
        <option value='23'>23</option>
        <option value='24'>24</option>
        <option value='25'>25</option>
        <option value='26'>26</option>
        <option value='27'>27</option>
        <option value='28'>28</option>
        <option value='29'>29</option>
        <option value='30'>30</option>
        <option value='31'>31</option>
        </select>
        </select>
          &nbsp;/&nbsp;
          <select name="date_m" class="NoSetWidthSelectBox">
          <option value'<? echo"$month"; ?>' selected><? echo"$month"; ?></option>
        <option value='01'>01</option>
        <option value='02'>02</option>
        <option value='03'>03</option>
        <option value='04'>04</option>
        <option value='05'>05</option>
        <option value='06'>06</option>
        <option value='07'>07</option>
        <option value='08'>08</option>
        <option value='09'>09</option>
        <option value='10'>10</option>
        <option value='11'>11</option>
        <option value='12'>12</option>
          </select>
          &nbsp;/&nbsp;
          <select name="date_y" class="NoSetWidthSelectBox">
        <option value='11' selected>2011</option>
        <option value='12'>2012</option>
        <option value='13'>2013</option>
        <option value='14'>2014</option>
        <option value='15'>2015</option>
        <option value='16'>2016</option>
        <option value='17'>2017</option>
        <option value='18'>2018</option>
        <option value='19'>2019</option>
        <option value='20'>2020</option>
          </select>
<select name="Category" class="NormalSelectBox">
          <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
          <?php $SQL = "SELECT * FROM " . $match_reports_cats_table . " WHERE active = 'y' ORDER BY name"; 
$result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Getting Catergories 1"); 
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$ID = $row["ID"];
$name = $row["name"]; ?>
          <option value="<?php echo stripslashes($row['name']); ?>"><?php echo stripslashes($row['name']); ?></option>
          <? } ?>
        </select>
<textarea name="Story" class="NormalTextArea"></textarea>
<input name="image" type="file" class="UploadTextBox">
        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="2048">
<select name="FrontPage" class="NoSetWidthSelectBox">
          <option selected='No' value='No'>No</option>
          <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
        </select>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Publish" class="publish_button" />
   <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save draft" class="NormalButton" />
    <input type="reset" value="Discard" class="NormalButton" />
```

and here is the process

```
if($_POST['btnSubmit'] == 'Save draft'){
//This gets all the other information from the form
    $target = "../../../images/matchreports/uploaded/";
    $target = $target . time() . '-' . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){  
    $Title=$_POST['Title'];
    $ShortTitle=$_POST['ShortTitle'];       
    $Story=$_POST['Story'];
    $Category=$_POST['Category'];
    $FrontPage=$_POST['FrontPage'];
    $image=time() . '-' . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);  
    $newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];
    $user_ip=$_POST['user_ip']; 

//Writes the information to the database        
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $match_reports_table . " (Title,ShortTitle,Story,Category,FrontPage,active,image,date,user_ip)VALUES ('$Title', '$ShortTitle', '$Story', '$Category', '$FrontPage', 'n', '$image', '$newdate', '" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "')") ;

    header("Location: /cms/matchreports/index.php?message=6");  
    exit;
 } else {

//This gets all the other information from the form
    $Title=$_POST['Title'];
    $ShortTitle=$_POST['ShortTitle'];       
    $Story=$_POST['Story'];
    $Category=$_POST['Category'];
    $FrontPage=$_POST['FrontPage'];
    $newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];
    $user_ip=$_POST['user_ip'];
//Writes the information to the database        
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $match_reports_table . " (Title,ShortTitle,Story,Category,FrontPage,active,date,user_ip)VALUES ('$Title', '$ShortTitle', '$Story', '$Category', '$FrontPage', 'n', '$newdate', '" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "')") ;

    header("Location: /cms/matchreports/index.php?message=7");  
    exit;}}
```

EDITED - Is this any better

```
$target = "../../../images/matchreports/uploaded/";
    $target = $target . time() . '-' . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){
    $image=time() . '-' . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);      
    $newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];
$SQL = "INSERT INTO " . $match_reports_table . " (Title,ShortTitle,Story,FrontPage,active,image,date,user_ip) VALUES('" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Title']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['ShortTitle']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Story']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['FrontPage']) . "','" . addslashes(y) . "','$image','$newdate','" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "')";
    $result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Publishing 1");
```

Comment: \*Waits for someone to scream "SQL Injection"\*

Comment: I was going to, but then I saw your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, holy sql injection batman.  Regardless, what you need to do is recreate the issue, and echo out the SQL being generated and handed off to mysql, and see what it looks like.  There is obviously a syntax error it and you will probably see it if you print out the query.

**EDIT:**

Change this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $match_reports_table . " (Title,ShortTitle,Story,Category,FrontPage,active,image,date,user_ip)VALUES ('$Title', '$ShortTitle', '$Story', '$Category', '$FrontPage', 'n', '$image', '$newdate', '" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "')") ;
```

To this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO " . $match_reports_table . " (Title,ShortTitle,Story,Category,FrontPage,active,image,date,user_ip)VALUES ('$Title', '$ShortTitle', '$Story', '$Category', '$FrontPage', 'n', '$image', '$newdate', '" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "')";
mysql_query($sql) ;
echo $sql;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

About the SQL Injection? Is that still at risk?

Comment: @outerhaven Ya, it definitely is, do some googling or look on SO, there is a lot of information on what it is, and how to prevent it.

Comment: @Outer: in regards to SQL injection, look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @outerhaven it's not getting that far then, do the same to all sql statements.  also make sure error reporting is turned on in your php that might offer some clues as well.  Perhaps look up some tutorials on debugging a php script.

Comment: Thanks.

I think I'll start from scratch and build from the ground up, without the risk of SQL Injection.

Comment: I've edited my post, with modifications. The script now works but is it better or worse with regards to SQL Injection?

Comment: @outerhaven addslashes is slightly better than nothing, but i'd recommend mysql_real_escape_string as Kyle R mentioned above, as well as doing your own checking on the form data to ensure that what is passed in looks like what it should.  Are number fields ints, are strings the right length, etc.  This comment string is getting pretty long, if you need help with sql injection probably start a new post. and if this answer helped you its customary to accept it.

Comment: I didn't want to start something new, but thanks for leading me in the right direction. I've accepted your answer, as if did in face help somewhat point me in the right direction.

I'll read up more about mysql_real_escape_string.

I know the data that is being passed looks correct, as I can see from the database it should as it should, and the page the reports display on on the main site etc.

Thanks again.

Comment: @outerhaven well you're not likely going to personally look at all the data, it may be right when you are putting it in, but out in the wild you should have the program do the checking because who knows what users may try to put in there.